# JQuery get closest td text value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

dears i have the following html

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center"><input type="text" class="form-control cardSerialNumber"></td>
    <td class="text-center"><button type="button" onclick="validateCardBeforeAssigning();" class="btn btn-success"><span style="color : white" class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span></button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center"><input type="text" class="form-control cardSerialNumber"></td>
    <td class="text-center"><button type="button" onclick="validateCardBeforeAssigning();" class="btn btn-success"><span style="color : white" class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span></button>

    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

So after clicking the btn i want to get the text (class cardSerialNumber) value from the same tr with closet td

i tried the following function but getting undefined always

```
function validateCardBeforeAssigning() {
  alert($(this).closest('tr').find('.cardSerialNumber').val());
}
```

your support, please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would certainly suggest using event handlers instead of an inline `onclick`. Give your buttons a unique class and apply the following jQuery:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success assign-card">
```

```
$(".assign-card").on("click", function() {
  alert($(this).closest('tr').find('.cardSerialNumber').val());
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
$(".assign-card").on("click", function() {
  alert($(this).closest('tr').find('.cardSerialNumber').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center"><input type="text" class="form-control cardSerialNumber"></td>
      <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success assign-card"><span style="color : white" class="glyphicon glyphicon-check">Assign</span></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center"><input type="text" class="form-control cardSerialNumber"></td>
      <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success assign-card"><span style="color : white" class="glyphicon glyphicon-check">Assign</span></button>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

If you were intent on simply fixing the code you have, which I don't recommend, you could do the following:

```
<button type="button" onclick="validateCardBeforeAssigning(this);" class="btn btn-success">
```

```
function validateCardBeforeAssigning(btn) {
    alert($(btn).closest('tr').find('.cardSerialNumber').val());
}
```

By changing your function to pass `this`, you get a reference to the button, whereas your use of `this` was not referring to any element.

**Demo:**

```js
function validateCardBeforeAssigning(btn) {
  alert($(btn).closest('tr').find('.cardSerialNumber').val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center"><input type="text" class="form-control cardSerialNumber"></td>
      <td class="text-center"><button type="button" onclick="validateCardBeforeAssigning(this);" class="btn btn-success"><span style="color : white" class="glyphicon glyphicon-check">Assign</span></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center"><input type="text" class="form-control cardSerialNumber"></td>
      <td class="text-center"><button type="button" onclick="validateCardBeforeAssigning(this);" class="btn btn-success"><span style="color : white" class="glyphicon glyphicon-check">Assign</span></button>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: it's working like a charm now :D, i used $(".assign-card").on("click", function() {

Answer (score 1):

Remove your inline JavaScript and instead use:

```
$('td.text-center button').click(function(){
  alert( $(this).closest('tr').find('.cardSerialNumber').val() );
})
```

You didn't pass a reference to the element you were clicking on your way so the function had no idea what `this` referred to

Answer (score 1):

You could also get the event (passed automatically from JS) inside the function, and 
then get the target of the event (your clicked button)

```
function validateCardBeforeAssigning(ev) {
  var target = ev.target;
  alert($(target).closest('tr').find('.cardSerialNumber').val());
}
```